# Minyan in public area

Tags: minyan, derech-eretz-manners, chilul-kidush-hashem

If a minyan is in a public hallway, blocking an exit at the end of that hallway, does the minyan have any halachic status to stop non Jews or women from walking through to reach that exit? This scenario occurred at a hall where people were forcefully blocked from passing through to reach the main exit to the parking lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "forcibly?" Where they strong arming people? turning them away? or merely sanding in place during shemonah esrei while other people walked around them or found a different exit? How remote was the end of the hallway? was there another reasonable place for them to congregate?

Comment: No. And Chazzal called someone praying in a public place a chatzif.

Comment: The Rabbim (public) had walking rights there before the Minyan did. The Minyan can't take away their rights. Same with someone davening Shemoneh Esrei in front of an aisle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "blocking an exit". Were they actually standing in the way of people trying to reach the exit? Then, obviously, yes, they *can* "prohibit non Jews or women from walking through to reach that exit": they did so. Or what is your question? Please [edit] it to clarify. Until that's done, I think this should be closed as unclear, just to make sure you don't get answers that don't address your actual concern. (cc @DoubleAA)

Comment: @msh210 I edited it. Is that OK?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok So you think people are physically stopping people and the asker wants to know whether they're halachically considered to be stopping people? Kinda like how someone can physically eat _matza_ (e.g. swallowing it whole or at gunpoint or taking a suppository) and the question is whether it's halachically considered eating? I'm not sure that's what the asker meant; and if it is, then it could still stand to be worded better for clarity (if you'll excuse my saying so).

Comment: @msh210 You're right insofar as "it could still stand to be worded better for clarity". What I meant was - did the people doing the stopping have any halachic justification for their actions.

Comment: Rav Herschel Schechter says not to make a minyan on a plane...I'm looking for that shiur on YUTorah.

Answer (score 1):

tThe Minyan has no halachik authority to block a public place for anybody. The mispallelim are out of their rights, and cannot compel others to walk around. (heard from R' Elyashiv, Zt"l)